# java: colorful system.out messages on console

Tags: java, unix, user-interface

I would like my command line java program to output colored texts into the unix console. I am specifically using gnome-terminal on Ubuntu 10.4. 
I am able to get colors with something like `echo "\033[01;32m"Hello` on the terminal.

How can I trigger this with java code? Thanks

Comment: i think there is no library for that but check  this guide for colors. http://bashscript.blogspot.com/2010/01/shell-colors-colorizing-shell-scripts.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't care about terminal compatibility, just replace `echo` with `System.out.println(` above. For example,

```
System.out.println("\033[01;32mHello\n");
```

Comment: I tried `System.out.println("\"\\033[01;32m\"Hello");` but it did not work.. The color prefix disappears, but the color does not change.

Comment: Too many escapes. Just something like `System.out.println("\033[01;32mHello\n");` works.

Comment: Just need to add \033[0m to the end of the string in order to revert to the default color.

Answer (score 4):

The color of text is at the OS layer so I think you can do it using JNI call.

[Try this example](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0469.html)

Note: make unix equivalent of that,

OR

[javacurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/) is also helpful in your case

OR

[enigma-shell](http://sourceforge.net/projects/enigma-shell/) is also helpful

Comment: This is a very informative answer. However, I'd rather go for a quick and simple solution for this one. such as using the `Runtime.getRuntime.exec()` method.

Answer (score 3):

This would do the trick:

`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo -e \"\\033[01;32m\"Could Not Add The Task!");`

Then redirect the inputStream into the System.out like this:

```
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

Comment: Well, certainly, it's possible, but why print the characters directly?